# evaluating curl of $\vec r/r^2$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

how do I calculate curl of :
$\vec r/r^2$
I don't know how to solve this problem can someone  help me please

Comment: Do you know the definition of the curl? Have you tried applying it? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @joriki I know little about curl and I am stuck with problems related to the m which I need to solve in a short dpan of time .Can you help me solve this problem.Iknow $\vec r/r^2$ is 0 but I don't know how to evaluate this

Comment: It would be nice to know what $r$ is.

Comment: @KingDuken $\vec r =(x,y,z)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\nabla \times (\phi \vec A)=\nabla (\phi) \times \vec A+\phi \nabla \times \vec A$.  Then, with $\phi=\frac{1}{r^2}$ and $\vec A=\vec r$, we have for $r\ne 0$

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times \left(\frac{\vec r}{r^2}\right)&=\nabla \left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\times \vec r+\frac{1}{r^2}\nabla \times \vec r\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

since $\nabla \left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)$ has only a radial component and $\nabla \times \vec r=0$ since the position vector is irrotational.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\nabla\times\pars{\vec{r} \over r^{2}}} & =
\nabla\times\bracks{\nabla\ln\pars{r}} = \color{#f00}{\vec{0}}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   \begin{align}
> \nabla\times\nabla\phi &= \sum_{i}\hat{e}_{i}
> \partiald{}{x_{i}}\times\sum_{j}\hat{e}_{j}\partiald{\phi}{x_{j}} =
> \sum_{i,j}{\partial^{2}\phi \over \partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}\,\hat{e}_{i}\times\hat{e}_{j} =
> \sum_{i,j}{\partial^{2}\phi \over \partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}\,
> \sum_{k}\epsilon_{ijk}\,\hat{e}_{k}
> \\[3mm] & =
> \sum_{k}\hat{e}_{k}\pars{\sum_{i,j}
> \epsilon_{ijk}\,{\partial^{2}\phi \over \partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}} =
> \half\sum_{k}\hat{e}_{k}\ \underbrace{\pars{\sum_{i,j}
> \epsilon_{ijk}\,{\partial^{2}\phi \over \partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}} +
> \epsilon_{jik}\,{\partial^{2}\phi \over \partial x_{j}\partial x_{i}}}}
> _{\ds{=\ 0}}
> \end{align}
>   whenever $\ds{{\partial^{2}\phi \over \partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}} = {\partial^{2}\phi \over \partial x_{j}\partial x_{i}}\,,\quad
> \forall\ i,j = x,y,z}$.